# Tikz - Rounded rectangle node position start arrow in middle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, nodes

I draw this simple graph:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert={outext=.svg,command=\unexpanded{pdf2svg \infile\space\outfile}},multi=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, arrows.meta, shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1.5cm]
    \tikzstyle{vertex} = [draw, rounded rectangle, minimum width=40pt, font=\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont];
    \node[vertex] (A) at (0, 0) {CAC};

    \node[vertex] (C) at (2, 0.5) {AC$\$_1$};
    \node (D) at (2, -0.5) {};
    
    \draw[->, font=\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont] (A) -- (C) node [midway, above] {$\$_1$};
    \draw[->, font=\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont] (A) -- (D) node [midway, above] {$\$_3$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thats produce this output:

[image: Wrong]

But I would create something like this:

[image]

Comment: Try giving your arrows more precise starting and ending points such as `(A.east)` and `(C.west)`. As for the arrow tips, add the option `>=stealth`. E.g. `\draw[->,>=stealth] (A.east) -- (C.west) node [midway, above] {$\$_1$};` (Change the font size at your disgression.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All nodes have anchors along their border, which can be used as coordinates. In general, the various compass directions (`north`, `north west`, `west`, etc.) are named anchors, and you can use an angle as well, if you want to. Some node shapes have other anchors. In the chapter about the `shapes` library, there is a diagram for each node shape that tells you where the anchors are.

The general syntax for using a node anchor as coordinate is `(<nodename>.<anchor>)`.
So to draw a line from the rightmost point of `A`, use `(A.east)` instead of just `(A)`, in the path drawing the line. E.g.

```
\draw (A.east) -- (C.west);
```

For the arrow moving down right, you could try using the `north west` anchor for `D`, and if that isn't good enough, you can shift the coordinate up a bit, like this:

```
([yshift=3pt]D.north west)
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, arrows.meta, shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1.5cm]
    \tikzstyle{vertex} = [draw, rounded rectangle, minimum width=40pt, font=\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont];
    \node[vertex] (A) at (0, 0) {CAC};

    \node[vertex] (C) at (2, 0.5) {AC$\$_1$};
    \node (D) at (2, -0.5) {};
    
    \draw[->, font=\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont] (A) -- (C) node [midway, above] {$\$_1$};
    \draw[->, font=\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont] (A) -- (D) node [midway, above] {$\$_3$};
    
    \draw[->, red, font=\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont] (A.east) -- (C.west) node [midway, above] {$\$_1$};
    \draw[->, red, font=\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont] (A.east) -- ([yshift=3pt]D.north west) node [midway, above] {$\$_3$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```